# Proof of Hensel's Lemma not clear

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, local-field, hensels-lemma

If you look at the following proof of Hensel's Lemma http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1472247.files/Hensels%20lemma.pdf you will see that the author determines the conditions which these elements $x_n$ must satisfy, then solves for what $x_n$ has to be as a result.  They do not actually show that the $x_n$ have the given properties that they claim.  In particular, they make the claim that $$w+f'(x_n)S \equiv 0 \pmod{\theta}$$ But if you look at how $w$ and $S$ are defined in the first place, it is not at all clear that this should be the case.

Comment: Hint: posting a link, instead of giving the proof directly in your question, greatly decreases the number of people who will seriously read the question.

Comment: The link to `isites.harvard.edu` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 0):

The claimed congruence $w+f'(x_n)S\equiv 0 \bmod \theta$ is clear from the line above, if you 
just divide by $\theta^n$, writing $f(x_n)=w\theta^n$: the congruence modulo $\theta^{n+1}$ is derived from the Taylor expansion
$$
f(x_n+\theta^nS)=f(x_n)+f'(x_n)\theta^nS+\frac{1}{2!}f''(x_n)\theta^{2n}S^2+\cdots + 
$$
Now consider this modulo $\theta^{n+1}$. Then
$$
w\theta^n+f'(x_n)\theta^n S \equiv 0\bmod \theta^{n+1},
$$
hence
$$
w+f'(x_n)S\equiv 0 \bmod \theta.
$$

Comment: I see that if you assume from the beginning that $f(x_n+ \theta^nS) \equiv 0 \pmod{\theta^{n+1}}$ (which the author seems to be assuming; he takes the elements $x_n$ with their properties for granted and derives what they should be), you can look at the formula $f(X+Y) = f(X) +$ etc. then divide out to get $w+f'(S) \equiv 0 \pmod{\theta}$.  Your argument appears to be circular and relies on the fact that the $x_n$ exist in the first place: I want to use the definition of the $x_n$ given by the author and prove that they have the required properties.

Comment: By induction $f(x_n) \equiv 0 \pmod{\theta^n}$, so $$f(x_{n+1}) = f(x_{n} + \theta^{n}S) = f(x_n) + f'(x_n)\theta^n + \cdots$$ should at least be $\equiv 0 \pmod{\theta^n}$.  Where does congruence modulo $\theta^{n+1}$ come from?

Comment: I promise you I understand algebraic number theory, I just don't understand this proof.